# Как изменить разрешение изображения в Android?

Tags: android

Есть приложение андроид(игра)
Как изменить разрешение изображения? Адаптировать под большой экран.

Comment: Игру вы пишете или это какая-то сторонняя игра?

Comment: сторонняя. В разработке я ноль без палочки, а разработчики не желают морочится

Comment: мне бы подсказку, а дальше разберемся)

Comment: Сходите на 4PDA - там Вы скорее найдёте помощь в ковырянии чужих поделок, и даже есть шанс, что Вашу хотелку там уже сделали.